# What useful GDB scripts have you used/written?

Tags: debugging, scripting, gdb

People use [gdb](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) on and off for debugging, 
of course there are lots of other debugging tools 
across the varied OSes, [with and without GUI and, 
maybe other fancy IDE features](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Debuggers).

I would like to know **[what useful gdb scripts you have written and liked](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb_22.html#SEC240)**.
While, I do not mean a dump of commands in a `something.gdb` file that you source to pull out a bunch of data, if that made your day, go ahead and talk about it.

- Lets think *conditional processing*, *control loops* and *functions* written for more elegant and refined programming to debug and, maybe even for whitebox testing
- Things get interesting when you start [debugging remote systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Debugger#Remote_debugging) (say, over a serial/ethernet interface)
- And, what if the target is a multi-processor (and, multithreaded) system

Let me put a simple case as an example...
Say,

> A script that traversed serially over entries
>   to locate a bad entry in a large hash-table
>   that is implemented on an embedded platform.

That helped me debug a broken hash-table once.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This script, not written by me, pretty prints STL containers, such as vector, map, etc: http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/src/dbinit_stl_views-1.03.txt

Totally awesome.

Comment: is this still necessary?

Answer (score 5):

When debugging an AOLserver SIGSEGV crash, I used the following script to examine the TCL-level call stack from GDB:

```
define tcl_stack_dump
  set $interp = *(Interp*)interp
  set $frame  = $interp->framePtr
  while (0 != (CallFrame *)$frame->callerPtr != 0)
    set $i = 0

    if 0 != $frame->objv
      while ($i < $frame->objc)
        if (0 != $frame->objv[$i] && 0 != $frame->objv[$i]->bytes)
          printf " %s", (char *)(CallFrame *)$frame->objv[$i]->bytes
        end

        set $i = $i + 1
      end
      printf "\n"
    end

    set $frame = (CallFrame *)$frame->callerPtr
  end
end

document tcl_stack_dump
  Print a list of TCL procs and arguments currently being called in an
  interpreter.  Most TCL C API functions beginning with Tcl[^_] will have a
  Tcl_Interp parameter.  Assumes the `interp' local C variable holds a
  Tcl_Interp which is represented internally as an Interp struct.

  See:
    ptype Interp
    ptype CallFrame
    ptype Proc
    ptype Command
    ptype Namespace
    ptype Tcl_Obj
end
```

Answer (score 3):

**1.** When trying to get some 3rd party closed-source DLLs working with our project under Mono, it was giving meaningless errors.  Consequently, I resorted to the scripts from the [Mono project](http://www.mono-project.com/Debugging#Debugging_with_GDB).

**2.** I also had a project that could dump it's own information to *stdout* for use in GDB, so at a breakpoint, I could run the function, then cut-n-paste its output into GDB.

*[Edit]*

**3.** Most of my GCC/G++ use has been a while, but I also recall using a macro to take advantage of the fact that GDB knew the members of some opaque data I had (the library was compiled with debug).   That was enormously helpful.

**4.** And I just found this, too. It dumps a list of objects (from a global "headMeterFix" SLL) that contain, among other things, dynamic arrays of another object type.  One of the few times I've used nested loops in a macro:

```
define showFixes
  set $i= headMeterFix
  set $n = 0
  while ($i != 0)
    set $p = $i->resolved_list
    set $x = $i->resolved_cnt
    set $j = 0 
    printf "%08x [%d] = {", $i, $x
    printf "%3d [%3d] %08x->%08x (D/R): %3d/%-3d - %3d/%-3d {", $n, $i, $x, $i->fix, $i->depend_cnt, dynArySizeDepList($i->depend_list), $i->resolved_cnt, dynArySizeDepList($i->resolved_list)
    while ($j < $x)
       printf " %08x", $p[$j]
       set $j=$j+1
    end
    printf " }\n"
    set $i = $i->next
    set $n = $n+1
  end
end
```

Comment: The Mono gdb reference is nice -- did not know about that. Not sure if I got your second part correctly, are you describing a function that was integrated into the project build to be called from a breakpoint in GDB? that is a good trick and was useful over a slow serial line debug interface in one of my projects.

Comment: W.r.t the 2nd part, it was long ago.  But yes, it was source code meant only to be called while at a breakpoint in GDB. I _think_ it was an attempt to track down some stack corruption with the help of the *__builtin_frame_address(n)* -- which is a macro and can't be called from GDB.